# sorting/scoring parent documents based on child field values

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
Types Description:  parent type
  1)Parent Type: "product"
  2)childType : "ratings"
```

**Description of problem** :i have an es query(query-1) which is working fine and fetching me results from parent Type(product), now i added a new type(ratings), and made the new type child of "product", and I need to extend this existing  **query** where the new results should get sorted based on the filed values of matched child(ratings) type.

query -1:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "has_parent" : {
        "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
              "term" : {
                "searchable" : "true"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "parent_type" : "supplierparent",
        "inner_hits" : { }
      }
    }, {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : {
          "query" : {
            "simple_query_string" : {
              "query" : "rice"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "nested" : {
        "query" : {
          "term" : {
            "productStatusList.status" : "Approved"
          }
        },
        "path" : "productStatusList"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there should be better ways to do this like we do with `nested` documents' attribute's sort. But one way with parent-child relation to sort can occur is on current type's attribute.

since they are now completely different document store, it would not be possible to use child property for sorting parent. There can be multiple children for the same parent doc, which would create ambiguity in sorting results.

Comment: Scenario in my case is, "ratings" type hold records of suppliers ratings and if i maintain these  docs in "product" as nested documents,then for every update in ratings for a supplier then all the products associated for supplier in "products" type need to be changed.

Would be much useful if you share how you guys are handling such scenarios.

Comment: can we also access child table fields using "doc[filedname]" ,as far as i remeber only current type fileds can be accesed, please let me know otherwise.

Any solution is much appreciated.

Comment: you are correct for child type doc they are removed the support. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16368